# Multivariable Limit problem , epsilon-delta

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

I am trying to solve this delta-epsilon problem, but I did not find an effective way to find the following limit:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (-3, 4)} \frac{2x^3 + 5y^3 + 18x^2 + 54x - 60y^2 + 240y - 266}{\sqrt{x^2 + 6x + 25 + y^2 - 8y}}$$

I actually tried a lot of inequalities (such as Cauchy-Schwarz), but nothing came up with this demonstration. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: make the substitution u=x+3, v=y-4, and switch into polar coordinatws

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After letting $x:=-3+r\cos(t)$ and $y:=4+r\sin(t)$ the limit becomes
$$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{r^3(2\cos^3 t+5\sin^3 t)}{r}=\lim_{r\to 0}r^2(2\cos^3 t+5\sin^3 t)=0$$
(note that $|(2\cos^3 t+5\sin^3 t)|\leq 2+5=7$).

Comment: thanks Robert Z, its helpful. actually, this method was not im my consideration, but now it is.

Comment: @Wilfred V You are welcome. BTW if you are new here take a few minutes for a tour https://math.stackexchange.com/tour